# What would you write as the object of this sentence?

Tags: sentence-structure, objects

> Learning to respect others is important.

Is the object: "to respect others" or "to respect"?

Comment: The only object is "others", which is object of "respect". The subordinate clause "to respect others" is complement of "learning".

Comment: @BillJ Hi. Uhm, thanks for your answer but if I ask a question like this: `Learning what is important?`, the response will be `to respect others.`. Am I wrong?

Comment: Yes, the noun phrase "others" is object of respect, but "to respect others" is not a noun phrase but a clause, and clauses can't be objects.

Comment: @BillJ "to respect others" isn't a subordinate clause; and clauses can be objects: "I know what you did last summer"

Comment: Within the gerund phrase, "Learning to respect others", "to respect others" is the object of the gerund "learning". "Others" is the only object of the sentence itself.

Comment: @gotube No, clauses can't be objects. In "I know [what you did last summer]", the bracketed element is a subordinate interrogative clause (embedded question) as complement of "know", not an NP object. And, "to respect others" is not object but complement of the catenative verb "learning".

Comment: @BillJ Why a complement and not an object? "Know" is a transitive verb. "I know [that you care]." The bracketed element is both an object and a clause.

Comment: @gotube "Know" can be trans or intrans. Declarative content clauses (_that_ clauses) are always complement of a verb or other element, but not objects. Some older out-of-date grammars say they are (calling them 'noun clauses'), but modern grammar correctly grammar says not.

Comment: Grammatical terminology is based on the choices of grammarians; it's not an objective truth that something is or isn't a clause or object. It seems perverse to say that "playing football" is a different thing in "He loved playing football" and "Playing football is fun": in both cases it can be qualified or modified in very similar ways.

Answer (score 0):

> *Learning* [*to respect others*] *is important*.

The bracketed element, an infinitival clause, is not object but complement of the catenative verb "learning".

Within the complement clause, the NP "others" is object of "respect".

There are no other objects.

Note that (with one minor exception) only NPs, not clauses, can be objects.

Comment: `Subordinate clauses, which can't stand alone, have three main purposes in life. A subordinate clause can describe nouns and pronouns; describe verbs, adverbs, and adjectives; or at act as the subject or object of another clause.` in here, it’s been stated that clauses can be objects.

Comment: @NUMERICALUDD That's wrong! A subordinate clause cannot function as an object. I've already told you that twice. Whoever or whatever told you otherwise is wrong. (Btw, they don't modify adverbs, either).